# Ruby style tips: Avoid eval, and keep things clear and orderly

Tags: ruby, arrays, eval

I'm confused on this one. I have a couple of viable solutions, but I don't like either of them. The problem at hand is that I am trying to generate a CSV in a Rails application. In my application specifically, I have a lot of values, around 30. Many of the values I would like displayed are also on associations, thus making the lines even longer... They look something like this (don't bother to read, just wanted you to have an idea of what i was talking about):

`[piece.client.organization, piece.client.category, piece.client.name , piece.campaign.name, piece.name, piece_url(piece.id), piece.campaign.election_date, piece.campaign.win_loss, piece.final_date, piece.local_photos, piece.killed, piece.format_list, piece.artist_list, piece.partner_list, piece.account_executive_list, piece.out_of_stock, piece.total_intake, piece.campaign.candidate_tags, piece.client.spec_list, piece.campaign.mail_poll]`

Except that they're even longer and more unwieldy. They work, but they make me feel bad inside. This is when I had the idea that I would just put them in a two-dimensional array, it instantly made the data look much more readable:

```
[["Client",       piece.client.organization], 
["Category",      piece.client.category], 
["Client Name",   piece.client.name] , 
...
["Campaign Name", piece.campaign.name], 
["Piece Name",    piece.name]]
```

That's great, now I can just loop over it to create my CSV rows... However, it will blow up based on where I need to define it as my "piece" is undefined. So then, I thought... what if I just wrap the second arguments in quotes and call eval on them later on when I need them? Then I looked it up, and people seem to say to use eval only to save lives...

Can anyone think of a simpler way to keep all of my data paired with column names, but maybe not use eval? Or maybe suggest that this would be a good use case for eval?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `eval` has never saved a life, and has probably endangered a couple.  :)

Comment: @counterbeing I am using the exact same style to create a csv. You can unclutter it further by skipping the internal inner brackets for each pair. Then, add ` ].in_groups_of(2)` at the end of the big array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually avoid `eval` by using blocks instead. For example, re-define your structure in terms of method calls:

```
columns = [
  [ "Client", lambda { |piece| piece.client.organization } ],
  [ "Category", lambda { |piece| piece.client.category } ],
  # ...
]
```

Then when iterating over your block, do something like this:

```
pieces.each do |piece|
  spec.each do |label, proc|
    value = proc.call(piece)

    # ... Do whatever you need here
  end
end
```

Defining blocks (Proc internally) can help define methods for doing things while deferring variable binding to some point in the future.

`eval` has a reputation for being dangerous because it can execute anything. It's best to avoid it unless there really is no other way.

Comment: Nice and complete answer. Thank you very much. All of those lambda blocks still make things look a little bit cluttered, but I'd say it's better than what I have. I'm experimenting with the stabby lambda syntax `->` now (lambdas are still somewhat abstract to me, but i'm getting it). Thanks again! I'm going to mark your answer unless something more succinct comes along shortly. Thanks again tadman!

Comment: Awesome, well, I think that does the job nicely. I'd like to add that the stabby syntax for declaring lambdas makes this a little easier on my eyes, it looks something like this now: `["Campaign",   -> campaign {campaign.name}]`